# require and module.exports : TypeError: X is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, require

## File structure :

```
server
├── controllers
│   ├── locationsController.js
│   ├── mainController.js
│   └── utilisateursController.js
├── models
│   ├── Locations.js
│   ├── Utilisateurs.js
|   └── ...
├── routes.js
└── server.js
```

In `mainController` I have a function `isValid` to check a string, I put it there because I want to access it from both `utilisateursController.js` and `locationsController.js`. I export it as follow :

### `mainController.js`

```js
const lc = require('./locationsController');
const uc = require('./utilisateursController');

// ...

module.exports = {
  // Associate all models
  associateAll: function () {
    lc.associateLocations();
    uc.associateUtilisateurs();
  },
  isValid: function(...fields) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
      if (fields[i] === undefined || fields[i] === null || fields[i] === '')
        return false;
    return true;
  }
};
```

## Problem

I can access the function `isValid` from `utilisateursController.js`, but when I try to do the same from `locationsController.js`, I have this error:

```
(node:6461) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: mc.isValid is not a function
    at exports.getAllTasks (.../server/controllers/locationsController.js:30:11)
```

## Code

### `utilisateursController.js`

From this file, I can perfectly access `isValid`, there is no error.

```js
const mc = require('./mainController');

// ...

exports.login = async function (req, res) {

  let response = {
    // ...
  }
  if (req.query == null) {
    response.infoMsg = 'Query empty...';
    res.send(response);
    return;
  }

  const usernameInput = req.query.username;
  const passwordInput = req.query.password;

  if (!mc.isValid(usernameInput, passwordInput)) {
    response.infoMsg = 'username or password is empty...'
    res.send(response);
    return;
  }

  // ...

}
```

### `locationsController.js`

From this file, I get the error mentioned above, and I really don't know why...

```js
const mc = require('./mainController');

// ...

exports.getAllTasks = async function (req, res) {
  let response = {
    // ...
  }

  const usernameInput = req.params.username;

  if (!mc.isValid(usernameInput)) {
    response.infoMsg = 'No parameters given...';
    res.send(response);
    return;
  }

  // ...

}
```

## What I think

I think it is maybe because of the order of the resolutions of the requires...

## What the debugger says

### `utilisateursController.js`

[image: utilisateurs]

### `locationsController.js`

[image: locations]

I really don't know what is causing this porblem...

Comment: Please have a read through the help's [mcve] section. Going through the process of creating a **minimal**, but complete, example is an important part of debugging, and (if you don't figure it out), asking a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact you have a circular relationship between `mainController`, `utilisateursController`, and `locationsController`. Both `utilisateursController` and `locationsController` require `mainController`, and `mainContoller` requires both `utilisateursController` and `locationsController`. As a result, Node.js's CommonsJS-style module resolution ends up running the top-level code in at least one (probably both) of your modules with a placeholder object for the exports of one of the other modules. (Apparently, in your case, `locationsController` gets a placeholder for `mainController`'s exports. `utilisateursController` probably does, too, but doesn't try to use it at the top level.)

If you avoid using `mc` at the top level, only using it in functions called later, that placeholder will get filled in before you need it and all will be well. The code you've quoted seems to only use `mc` within a function, but given the error you're getting, apparently that's not true of your real code.

More in the [Node.js modules documentation's "Cycles" section](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

---

Side note: This doesn't happen with native JavaScript modules (often called "ESM" for "**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules), because even when there are circular dependencies, they're resolved before the top-level module code gets run.

Comment: Thank you! I put `isValid` to a helper file to avoid circular relationships

Comment: @davalres - Sounds perfect, nice one! :-)

Comment: Another question, if I replace my condition in my `isValid` function by `return !!fields[i]`, would it have the exact same effect ? I am exploring truthy/falsy concept in JS (because truthy values of `undefined`, `null` and `''` are `false`, right ?).

Comment: @DavidAlvarez - No, that would be different for two reasons: 1. You'd return the flag for just the first field, since `return` terminates the function. 2. There are several values that aren't on your list that are falsy, such as `0` and `NaN`. Your original checks specifically for three of the falsy values (`undefined`, `null`, and `""`), but the full list is `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. (All other values are truthy.)

Comment: Thank you for helping me understanding the concept !